# How to change the cursor before a long task?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I want to change the cursor before a long task. I changed it with setcursor, but the cursor didn't change.

Here is my code:

```
    HCURSOR hWait  =  AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_WAIT) ;
    HCURSOR hDefault = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW);
    ::SetCursor(hWait);

    //a long procedure

    ::SetCursor(hDefault);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131991

Comment: Sorry, That's my stupid mistake. I added my code to wrong message handler. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A very handy way of doing it is by creating an instance of [CWaitCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7bzytb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) at the start (or just before) of the long task. It sets the cursor and when it goes out of scope it restores it (in the destructor):

```
{
    CWaitCursor wait;  

    // Long task

} // The cursor is restored here
```

Comment: IMO, `CWaitCursor` is mostly useless.  If you have a long running task that's preventing your window from processing messages, then your window will become unresponsive (and might stop painting).  If you are processing messages, then the cursor might be reset, and you instead should be handling `WM_SETCURSOR` messages.

Comment: @jamesdlin I've never had any problems with it. And, by looking at its code, I would say that it does the same as `::SetCursor()`. In fact, the constructor of `CWaitCursor` calls `CCmdTarget::BeginWaitCursor()`, who calls `CWinApp::DoWaitCursor()` who calls `::SetCursor()`.

Comment: `WM_SETCURSOR` is not the same as `SetCursor`. If you're processsing window messages while you're waiting, your window must handle (not send) `WM_SETCURSOR` and call `SetCursor`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/21/1115695.aspx